# Should I use ActiveModel for this simple non-database Rails application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activemodel

I'm building a simple two page Rails application where a user:

1. Enters credit card details on first page and clicks 'Next'.
2. Enters billing address on second page and clicks 'Submit'.

I will have an overall Order model that will validate the data entered.

I don't require a database for this application as I'll be storing data in session between pages. Should I use ActiveModel for something so simple?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should use ActiveModel only if you want to validate your input data. And if not - you can just use session.
Also this would be helpful: [ActiveModel railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/219-active-model)

if you haven't seen it.